# A lightning-fast StringBuilder

Tags: strings, vba

In the process of trying to build a serializable data structure, I found myself building large strings, which gets very slow because VBA copies a string every time concatenation is performed.

To alleviate this, referring to [Dynamic Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) and Java's StringBuilder interface, I cobbled together a unicode `clsStringBuilder` class.

This isn't a very big chunk of code, but I'd be interested in any advice about edge cases that I maybe haven't considered, unexpected copying behavior that VBA might be performing "behind my back" which I could avoid, or corrections to coding style (or lack thereof).

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'******
'* v2 *
'******


Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal dst As Long, ByVal src As Long, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Const DEFAULT_CAPACITY As Long = &H10
Private m_currLen As Long
Private m_stringBuffer() As Byte

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim m_stringBuffer(0 To (DEFAULT_CAPACITY * 2) - 1) 'Each unicode character is 2 bytes
End Sub

Public Function Append(strString As String) As clsStringBuilder
On Error GoTo derp


    If m_currLen + LenB(strString) < UBound(m_stringBuffer) Then
        CopyMemory VarPtr(m_stringBuffer(m_currLen)), StrPtr(strString), LenB(strString)
    Else
        If m_currLen + LenB(strString) < UBound(m_stringBuffer) * 2 Then
            Expand
        Else
            Expand m_currLen + LenB(strString)
        End If
        CopyMemory VarPtr(m_stringBuffer(m_currLen)), StrPtr(strString), LenB(strString)
    End If
    m_currLen = m_currLen + LenB(strString)
    Set Append = Me
    Exit Function

derp:
    Stop
    Resume
End Function

Public Property Get Length() As Long
    Length = m_currLen / 2
End Property

Public Property Get Capacity() As Long
    Capacity = UBound(m_stringBuffer)
End Property

Private Sub Expand(Optional newSize As Long = 0)
    If newSize <> 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve m_stringBuffer(0 To newSize - 1)
    Else
        ReDim Preserve m_stringBuffer(0 To (UBound(m_stringBuffer) * 2) + 1)
    End If
End Sub

Public Function toString() As String
    toString = Mid(m_stringBuffer, 1, m_currLen / 2)
End Function
```

Here is a test:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim sb As clsStringBuilder
    Set sb = New clsStringBuilder
    Dim strString As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim StartTime As Double

    'VBA String
    StartTime = MicroTimer()
    For i = 0 To 100000
        strString = strString + "Hello World;"
    Next
    Debug.Print "The VBA String took: " & Round(MicroTimer - StartTime, 3) & " seconds"

    'StringBuilder
    StartTime = MicroTimer()
    For i = 0 To 100000
        sb.Append "Hello World;"
    Next
    Debug.Print "The Stringbuilder took: " & Round(MicroTimer - StartTime, 3) & " seconds"

    'Are the strings the same?
    Debug.Print StrComp(strString, sb.toString, vbBinaryCompare)
End Sub
```

Here is Microsoft's `MicroTimer` function, which can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700515(v=office.14).aspx#Office2007excelPerf_MakingWorkbooksCalculateFaster):

```
Private Declare Function getFrequency Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "QueryPerformanceFrequency" (cyFrequency As Currency) As Long
Private Declare Function getTickCount Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "QueryPerformanceCounter" (cyTickCount As Currency) As Long
Function MicroTimer() As Double
'

' Returns seconds.
    Dim cyTicks1 As Currency
    Static cyFrequency As Currency
    '
    MicroTimer = 0

' Get frequency.
    If cyFrequency = 0 Then getFrequency cyFrequency

' Get ticks.
    getTickCount cyTicks1

' Seconds
    If cyFrequency Then MicroTimer = cyTicks1 / cyFrequency
End Function
```

Comment: Hey Blackhawk - I've tweaked this code a bit and [uploaded it on GitHub](https://github.com/retailcoder/VBA-StringBuilder), and I don't know if you saw Tim Hall's [VBA-Blocks](https://vba-blocks.com), but I think it would be awesome to have a `StringBuilder` class available through a nuget-like package manager for VBA (and Rubberduck might eventually craft a UI for it, so packages for a project can be add/updated/maintained, all in the VBE). Would be awesome if you could contact Tim to agree with what I've done with your code (or I can take down that repository if you prefer) - LMK!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon That's awesome! If you need me to poke anybody, let me know, but otherwise consider this comment a stamp of approval :)

Comment: I have tried the Darin version of this solution and I agree it is lightning fast; about ten times faster that writing each append to disc which was my best solution.  But how?  All versions use `ReDim Preserve` per append. I have not timed `ReDim Preserve` myself but there are websites which explain why it is slow and include timings to prove it. I wondered if the performance was the result of all the appends being in a tight loop but my attempts at interfering failed to damage it.  How can the Byte array be made longer millions of times without this resulting in a painfully slow routine?

Comment: @Blackhawk  I know this is an old posting but if any of the original authors are still around, could they please explain why this solution works.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  I know this is an old posting but if any of the original authors are still around, could they please explain why this solution works.

Comment: @user28366.  I know this is an old posting but if any of the original authors are still around, could they please explain why this solution works.

Comment: @Martin.Roller  I know this is an old posting but if any of the original authors are still around, could they please explain why this solution works.

Comment: @TonyDallimore if you notice where the resizing is happening, you see that it's *doubling* the buffer capacity every time it resizes, instead of systematically resizing at every append. And then `CopyMemory` is used to write the string bytes to the buffer directly; it's no surprise everything happening in-memory is much faster than anything involving disk I/O.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon.  Thank you.  The in-memory aspect of the solution was obvious but I missed the nature of the `ReDim Preserve`s.  I see so much code with each `ReDim Preserve` adding a single element that I did not look carefully.  Doubling the size of the array each time would require only three `ReDim Preserve`s in my experiment and probably did not need a single garbage collection.

Comment: @TonyDallimore to add a bit more clarification, the most expensive part of the standard `ReDim Preserve` is the *copy*. When you have a chunk of memory and you want to "expand" it by just one character, what actually happens is the OS has to find a completely new chunk of memory that is the new requested size, and then it has to copy everything from the old chunk into the new chunk. This takes longer and longer as your data grows. Imagine building a 2GB array expanding 1 byte at a time - you'd end up making ~ 2 billion copies totaling ~ 2 billion GB!

Comment: @TonyDallimore To expand on that math (so you can double check me) you're talking about copying 1 byte, then 2 bytes, then 3, then 4, 5, etc. which is a triangle number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number. The formula for calculating the total number of bytes copied is (n(n+1))/2, where n is 2 GB = (2*1024^3), and then divide the result by (1024^3) to get GB.

Comment: @Blackhawk Thanks for the comments.  I understand the principle of how string concatenation and `ReDim Preserve` work behind the scenes.  I see `ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To UBound(Arr) + 1)` so often I did not study your code carefully enough.  Once, MathieuGuindon had pointed out that each ReDim doubled the size of the array, not just added enough for the next append, the reason for your code being so fast was obvious.

Comment: Blackhawk and @Mathieu: brilliant, thanks a lot. I'm using it for last couple years and cannot VBA without anymore.
I grabbed Mat's Mug's version at GitHub and tweaked it a little to add an Append with linebreak based on a line length limit on a setter. And added some setters like AvoidLineBreakAfterLastLine and IndentLineAfterBreak to turn life easier.

Comment: @MarceloScofano good stuff! If I recall though, I made a mistake somewhere along the way and lost a massive amount of performance.. and never bothered to fix it. blackhawk's original still makes a better starting point I think.

Comment: @Mathieu: well, in that case I'll do some tests; but until now I didn't have any obvious performance issues. If I fix them I'll fork and do a pull request on your git.

Comment: @Mathieu: You are partially right; using the test above:
_The VBA String took:_ 68,107 seconds;    
_The MatsMugStringbuilder took:_ 0,883 seconds;   
_The BlackhawkStringbuilder took:_ 0,396 seconds;    

and both StringBuilder versions avoid **Out of String Space**...  No big deal under 10K concatenations.

Comment: Here is an alternative solution that runs the speed test in 0.031 seconds: [StringBuffer](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-StringBuffer) using just the ```Mid``` statement (left side of assignment) and no external APIs or arrays

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I like this, a lot. It's.. brilliant. Like .NET `String` objects, VBA strings are immutable, which means like in .NET, when `"the quick brown fox"` gets appended with `"jumps over"` and then `"the lazy dog"`, it's 4 strings that have been generated, and thus the first one got copied 3 times; a VBA `StringBuilder` class is therefore definitely welcome to any VBA toolkit!

This is some serious code you've got here. Let's take a look.

So you've called the class `clsStringBuilder`. I know where you're coming from, but there's no real reason for this "cls" Hungarian prefix - I'd remove it, and call the class `StringBuilder`.

> ```
> '******
> '* v2 *
> '******
> ```

Don't bother with that. I know version control is natively near-impossible with VBA, but there is no need to "version" code in comments nonetheless; do you actually maintain the version number? Why bother? Just remove it, it's useless clutter.

> ```
> Private Const DEFAULT_CAPACITY As Long = &H10
> ```

Why not `16`? Hexadecimal `10` is `16` right? I think it would be clearer to use a decimal notation. Actually that capacity is potentially confusing, especially given the hex notation. Is `&H10` the number of bytes? Characters?

> ```
> ReDim m_stringBuffer(0 To (DEFAULT_CAPACITY * 2) - 1) 'Each unicode character is 2 bytes
> ```

Ah, characters then. How about calling the constant `DEFAULT_CHARACTER_CAPACITY`? Nah, too long.. and I personally don't like the YELLCASE, I'd just call it `InitialCharacterCapacity`, but I've seen other people use ALL CAPS for constants - as long as you're consistent, it works :)

BTW that's a good comment you have there, but I wouldn't bother specifying "unicode" characters; it gets confusing when the IDE itself only supports ANSI strings!

I don't like prefixes and abbreviated names, so `m_currLen` would become `currentLength` and `m_stringBuffer` would become `stringBufffer`, or just `buffer`.

Actually since `currentLength` is in bytes, I'd call it `currentByteLength`, so as to avoid question marks when it comes to this:

> ```
> Public Property Get Length() As Long
>     Length = m_currLen / 2
> End Property
> ```

---

> ```
> Public Function Append(strString As String) As clsStringBuilder
> ```

`strString`, really? I doesn't get any more Hungarian than that! Also you should know that parameters are passed `ByRef` by default - I'd change the signature to this:

```
Public Function Append(ByVal value As String) As StringBuilder
```

The error handling isn't optimal - if anything blows up, you're bringing up the IDE for the end user to scratch their head and debug your code! That's not production-ready:

> ```
> derp:
>     Stop
>     Resume
> ```

"derp" means nothing to me - I like following a "template" like this:

```
Public Sub Foo()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    'implementation

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    'handle error
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

---

You might also want to make sure `Expand` doesn't actually *shrink* the buffer. I think. ;)

Lastly, I'm not sure I understand why `toString` isn't following the convention and named in `PascalCase` like every public method - `ToString` would be better-looking.

Good job!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - fixing the naming conventions now. For the member variables, I've often run into cases where I need to make them private and provide access through Get/Set/Let properties. In those cases, I use "m_" to keep VBA from yelling "Ambiguous name detected: membername".  What is the best practice for those situations?

Comment: I like stuffing all my private fields into a private type - here would be `Private Type TStringBuilder`, with all the members. Then the class only has 1 field, which I call `this`, like, `Private this As TStringBuilder` - this eliminates the name clashes, and I like seeing `this.MemberName = value` in a `Public Property Let MemberName(ByVal value As Whatever)` block ;)

Comment: Interesting... I like this :D I'll have to think through the implications...

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I like YELLCASE constants...

Answer (score 19):

Your `StringBuilder` is pretty damn impressive :) ++ to Mat's suggestions except the [YELLCASE which I am on RubberDuck's side](http://vba4all.com/vba-syntax/) ;)

I think I have identified a potential overflow of memory (*`out of memory`*). It's probably very unlikely to happen to anyone but hey... If you wrap your loop with another loop VBA runtime doesn't seem to catch up with counting and releasing the references...Your `StringBuilder` is too damn quick to VBA runtime ;)

Ex:

```
For j = 0 To 1000
    Dim csb As New clsStringBuilder

    StartTime = MicroTimer()
    For i = 0 To 100000
        csb.Append "Hello World;"
    Next
Next
```

That will stop in `derp` at some point and cause an `out of memory`... AFAIC, nothing you can really do... except don't allow people like me to test your code ;P jk!

A few other minor things from me though:

□ `Select Case` is faster than `If-Else`

□ Division is more expensive than addition & multiplication

□ Multiple computation to get the same number is a bit inefficient. If you need to get the value of `Ubound(arr)` 5 times within one *if-else/select case* consider storing this number in a variable.

□ [`Mid$()` (in *`ToString()`*) should be a tiny bit faster than `Mid()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519579/mid-vs-mid)

□ Probably a safer option to use `&` instead of `+` for String concatenation. (*your `Main()`*)

Overall speed seems just a tiny bit faster with my *improvements* - too subtle? ;)

1000 tests each

[image]

Ok I just changed the name to `StringBuilder` and here's what I've done to it:

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (ByVal dst As Long, ByVal src As Long, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Const DEFAULT_CAPACITY As Long = 16
Private m_currLen As Long
Private m_stringBuffer() As Byte

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim m_stringBuffer(0 To (DEFAULT_CAPACITY + DEFAULT_CAPACITY) - 1) 'Each unicode character is 2 bytes
End Sub

Public Function Append(strString As String) As StringBuilder
On Error GoTo derp

    Dim uBuffer As Long
    uBuffer = UBound(m_stringBuffer)

    Dim lengthB As Long
    lengthB = LenB(strString)

    Dim sPtr As Long
    sPtr = StrPtr(strString)

    Dim currLen As Long
    currLen = m_currLen + lengthB

    Select Case currLen
        Case Is < uBuffer
            CopyMemory VarPtr(m_stringBuffer(m_currLen)), sPtr, lengthB
        Case Is < (uBuffer + uBuffer)
            Expand
            CopyMemory VarPtr(m_stringBuffer(m_currLen)), sPtr, lengthB
        Case Else
            Expand currLen
            CopyMemory VarPtr(m_stringBuffer(m_currLen)), sPtr, lengthB
    End Select

    m_currLen = currLen
    Set Append = Me
    Exit Function

derp:
    Stop
    Resume
End Function

Public Property Get Length() As Long
    Length = m_currLen * 0.5
End Property

Public Property Get Capacity() As Long
    Capacity = UBound(m_stringBuffer)
End Property

Private Sub Expand(Optional newSize As Long = 0)
    Select Case newSize
        Case Is = 0
            ReDim Preserve m_stringBuffer(0 To (UBound(m_stringBuffer) + UBound(m_stringBuffer)) + 1)
        Case Else
            ReDim Preserve m_stringBuffer(0 To newSize - 1)
    End Select
End Sub

Public Function ToString() As String
    ToString = Mid$(m_stringBuffer, 1, m_currLen * 0.5)
End Function
```

You could possibly play a bit more with the `Select Case` but I've left it in a state that I am happy with...

`m_stringBuffer(m_currLen)` should be *`O(1)`* so no need to store in a variable IMO

Comment: Thanks! Working through this now... what did you use to generate the fancy chart?

Comment: you can't be serious with your question? :P Excel 2010...

Comment: Ah, of course - it was the colors that threw me, since they aren't the canned "Office pastels"

Comment: @Blackhawk no worries ;) I probably wouldn't guess myself hehe I bet we all got our favorite RGBs ;)

Comment: @user28366 You've fallen victim to VBA's `As New` syntax. Using `Dim csb As New StringBuilder` in a loop **does NOT** create a new instance on each iteration, so you're only ever working with the first instance and you're effectively adding `"Hello World;"` a mere 100m times. That's a `String` in excess of 2GB, at 2,402,424,024 bytes, or a `Long` overflow well before you run out of memory. The overflow problem isn't with the `StringBuilder` class, it's with your over-usage of it. The open-source VBE add-in *Rubberduck VBA* (to which I'm a contributor) would have spotted that oversight.

Answer (score 11):

Using `CopyMemory` is actually unnecessary, you can achieve the same thing simply with arrays. The code is not only shorter but faster as well.

```
Dim MyBuffer() As String
Dim MyCurrentIndex As Long
Dim MyMaxIndex As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    MyCurrentIndex = 0
    MyMaxIndex = 16
    ReDim MyBuffer(1 To MyMaxIndex)

End Sub

'Appends the given Text to this StringBuilder
Public Sub Append(Text As String)

    MyCurrentIndex = MyCurrentIndex + 1

    If MyCurrentIndex > MyMaxIndex Then
        MyMaxIndex = 2 * MyMaxIndex
        ReDim Preserve MyBuffer(1 To MyMaxIndex)
    End If
    MyBuffer(MyCurrentIndex) = Text

End Sub

'Returns the text in this StringBuilder
'Optional Parameter: Separator (default vbNullString) used in joining components
Public Function ToString(Optional Separator As String = vbNullString) As String

    If MyCurrentIndex > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve MyBuffer(1 To MyCurrentIndex)
        MyMaxIndex = MyCurrentIndex
        ToString = Join(MyBuffer, Separator)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation, how and why this is better than what OP posted. Also note that this question is already quite old (and here we don't care about canonical answers, but the actual review of the code), so the OP might have moved on.

Comment: @Martin.Roller Just looking at the code it would seem that MyCurrentIndex needs to be incremented. Is that so??       myCurrentIndex = myCurrentIndex + Len(Text) - 1

Comment: @donPablo: Look again or try stepping through the code. The length of the Text is irrelevant.

Comment: @Blackhawk: Note that speed here only depends on the number of appends, not on the size of the appended text.

Comment: This is clearly the version to use, only one with no 32/64 bits portablity issues.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez this is in act much faster. I have found no instance in which copymemory makes a program faster. Is this due to having to call varptr()? Switching from userspace to kernel space?

Comment: @PatrickHonorez also could this best described as a custom allocator/local allocator?

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question but people finding it may find this answer of value.  I've tested 4 versions of StringBuilder using Excel 2013 and the fastest version appears to be an optimized version of Blackhawk's code (The optimized code listed below).  The list below shows one example of the time it took each version to do Blackhawk's test 1000 times (100,000,000 total appends).  The new optimized version is labeled "New" and took a little longer than 34 seconds.  Martin.Roller's array-based code is labeled "Ary", takes a little more than 36 seconds, and is nearly tied with Blackhawk's code.  I've ran the test several times and Blackhawk's code does come in ahead of Martin.Roller's code some of the time.  Blackhawk's code is labeled "Old" and takes a little more than 36 seconds.  The "Mid" version came in last and is a version I created using VBA's MID statement to replace the content of a string.  Removing the "On Error" in the code below should improve the speed even more, but make sure the calling code never builds a string longer than VBA can handle.

1. The New StringBuilder took: 34.396 seconds
2. The Ary StringBuilder took: 36.467 seconds
3. The Old StringBuilder took: 36.605 seconds
4. The Mid StringBuilder took: 40.141 seconds

New optimized version of Blackhawk's StringBuilder:

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal dst As Long, ByVal src As Long, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Const InitialCharCount As Long = 16
' Define members
Private mUBound As Long
Private mString() As Byte

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Clear
End Sub

Public Sub Clear()
    mUBound = -1
    ReDim mString(0 To InitialCharCount * 2 - 1) 'Each unicode character is 2 bytes
End Sub

Public Function Append(value As String) As StringBuilder
Dim NewUBound As Long
Dim CapacityUBound As Long
On Error GoTo Failed
    NewUBound = mUBound + LenB(value)

    If NewUBound > UBound(mString) Then
        CapacityUBound = UBound(mString) * 2 + 1
        If NewUBound > CapacityUBound Then CapacityUBound = NewUBound * 2 + 1
        ReDim Preserve mString(0 To CapacityUBound)
    End If
    CopyMemory VarPtr(mString(mUBound + 1)), StrPtr(value), LenB(value)

    mUBound = NewUBound
    Set Append = Me
    Exit Function

Failed:
    Stop
    Resume
End Function

Public Property Get Length() As Long
    Length = (mUBound + 1) / 2
End Property

Public Function ToString() As String
    ToString = Mid(mString, 1, Length)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this! In the spirit of the question, can you add a description of the optimizations you made? That will help anyone looking at this answer to understand what changes cause the speedup. I have to say, one of the things that I love about VBA is the *lack* of a standard library - you get to learn how to roll your own everything :)