# Concatenate disjoint Excel ranges to use as a single range in a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I need to vertically concatenate two disjoint ranges in VBA to be passed to an Excel function (in this case the `LINEST` function). I hate working with arrays in VBA but I managed to get it working using the following code:

```
Option Base 1

Function VERTCAT(R1 As Range, R2 As Range) As Variant

    Dim ncols As Integer
    ncols = R1.Columns.Count
    Dim nrows1 As Integer
    nrows1 = R1.Rows.Count
    Dim nrows2 As Integer
    nrows2 = R2.Rows.Count

    Dim arr1 As Variant
    arr1 = R1
    Dim arr2 As Variant
    arr2 = R2

    Dim arr3 As Variant
    ReDim arr3(nrows1 + nrows2, ncols)

    For Col = 1 To ncols
        For Row = 1 To nrows1
            arr3(Row, Col) = arr1(Row, Col)
        Next Row
        For Row = 1 To nrows2
            arr3(Row + nrows1, Col) = arr2(Row, Col)
        Next Row
    Next Col

    VERTCAT = arr3

End Function
```

I'm not worried about adding basic error checking, like making certain that the two arrays have the same number of columns or adding features. I am hoping that someone can show me what the idiomatic VBA way is to have written this function? Could I have avoided some of the helper variables (like `arr3` for example?)? Could I have avoided the loops?

Comment: Wouldn't `Union` function help eliminate the loop for joining rows at least? Also you have a fundamental error in the `ReDim arr3(nrows1 + nrows2, ncols)` as it creates a new array starting at 0. You should change it to `ReDim arr3(1 to tonrows1 + nrows2, ncols)` to keep the correct dimensions

Comment: I tried to use `UNION` initially but to no avail. Can you show an example?

Comment: Also doesn't the `Option Base 1` take care of the `ReDim`? I have tested this code and it does work

Comment: oh ive missed the `option base 1` sorry I use the default

Comment: are you planning to work with more than 1 column per range?

Comment: @Meehow yes many columns, for example we wrote this as a helper function so that we could drag down formulae using the `LINEST` function. We needed to convert disjoint ranges into a single range to feed to [`LINEST`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LINEST-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d) as the *known_xs* (second) parameter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question, no. There is no "idiomatic" way to combine multiple arrays together without creating a bigger array (or extending one of the originals) and manually copying in the array contents.

Anyway, while I'm here,

### Miscellaneous Points

I don't know if you just left it out, but if it's not there, `Option Explicit` should be at the top of every single code module everywhere. IF you don't have it enabled, go to Tools --> Options --> Require Variable Declaration.

Your function is **implicitly** public because you didn't scope it. **Explicitly scope everything**. Assuming you want to use it in other modules, it should be `Public Function VERTCAT() as Variant`.

`Integer` is outdated. Unless you're in a position where 4 bytes of memory has serious performance impacts, use `Long` instead. `Integer` will fail if you give it a number greater than about 33,000, that's a number that could reasonably occur when dealing with big spreadsheets. `Long` will handle numbers up to 2.1 Billion and is also (marginally) faster.

### **Variable Naming**

First off, `VERTCAT` violates several good practices.

Standard VBA convention for function/procedure names is `PascalCase`. `VERTCAT` is also distinctly unclear and ambiguous. Names should always be **clear**, **concicse** and most importantly, **unambiguous**.

If I see `VERTCAT` I'm going to think "What does this do? Vertically... catenate?". Okay, but catenate what? Strings? Lists? Ranges? Arrays? `VerticallyConcatenateRanges` really isn't very long, and is absolutely clear on what it takes as parameters, and what it does to them. Depending on your style, you might consider `ArrayFromConcatenatedRanges` to be even better.

If in doubt, always err on the side of more verbose.

**VBA conventions you should be aware of:**

Function/Procedure names are `PascalCase`.

Local variable names are `camelCase` so `nCols` instead of `ncols` and `col` instead of `Col`.

N.B. if `Col` is capitalised because it's a module-level variable, that's an even worse offence (unnecessarily broad scope) than bad naming.

Module/Global variable names are `PascalCase` so if I see `ReferenceVariable` in the middle of a procedure, I know to look for it outside of that procedure's scope.

**And now for your variables**

`R1` and `R2` are terrible variable names. **Variables should always sound like what they are**. I suggest `topRange`,`bottomRange`. Suddenly, it's clear that they are ranges, and that the first one is the one that's going to end up on top of the final concatenation.

Similarly, `ncols`,`nrows1`,`nrows2` are not great. It should be `nCols`, `nRows1`, `nRows2` anyway, and then `numColumns`,`rowsInTopRange`,`rowsInBottomRange` still sound like counts of rows/columns, but it's much clearer what they are/should be. Similarly, `arr1` and `arr2` could do with the same treatment.

This is your code, with better naming, and it is **so** much easier for someone to read/follow:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Function VerticallyConcatenateRanges(topRange As Range, bottomRange As Range) As Variant

    Dim row As Long, col As Long

    Dim numColumns As Long
        numColumns = topRange.Columns.Count

    Dim rowsInTopRange As Long
        rowsInTopRange = topRange.Rows.Count

    Dim rowsInBottomRange As Long
        rowsInBottomRange = bottomRange.Rows.Count

    Dim totalRows As Long
        totalRows = rowsInTopRange + rowsInBottomRange

    Dim arrTopRange As Variant
        arrTopRange = topRange

    Dim arrBottomRange As Variant
        arrBottomRange = bottomRange

    Dim concatenatedArray As Variant
    ReDim concatenatedArray(1 To totalRows, 1 To numColumns)

    Dim ix As Long

        For col = 1 To numColumns

            For row = 1 To rowsInTopRange
                concatenatedArray(row, col) = arrTopRange(row, col)
            Next row

            For row = 1 To rowsInBottomRange
                ix = row + rowsInTopRange
                concatenatedArray(ix, col) = arrBottomRange(row, col)
            Next row

        Next col

        VerticallyConcatenateRanges = concatenatedArray

End Function
```

And, crucially, if you took any of those lines out of context and gave them to someone, that person would be able to figure out very easily what the variables were and what the code was doing.

Comment: FWIW the `Integer` max value is 32767, not 33000 ;-)

Comment: I did say "about" :)

Comment: Relevant reading: [Why use long instead of integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520)

Comment: Thanks, helpful points. I'm not a fan of VBA at all but will try implement some of these best practices going forward! Incidentally, I called it `VERTCAT` as that's the name of the function in MATLAB which we use more often.

Comment: You mentioned adding on to an existing array, would that have been a better idea? Shold I have `redim`ed `arrTopRange` and not used `concatenatedArray`?

Comment: Either is fine really. Just remember, if you're going to use one of the existing arrays, to call the function something like "AppendArray" instead.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, after some thinking about this I was able to come up with a solution that may suit your case a little better then loops. My solution actually eliminates all the heavy loops and only contains one loop that builds up a query ( you could also enhance the performance of that single loop by using [**A lightning-fast StringBuilder**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/67596/28366)

I'm using ADODB library (*tools - references - Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library*) to query a worksheet using a UNION ALL sql syntax to select into one column from multiple ranges.

This may change the way you are passing in `Range`s to the function but makes code a lot clearer and much more optimised.

Consider the following: instead of passing ex. `Range("A1:B10")` you would want to make sure that you're passing the Ranges as single columns like `Range("A1:A10"), Range("B1:B10")`. The [`ParamArray`](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optionalargumentstoprocedures.aspx) allows you to pass as many columns as you like.

The final result of the below sample returns a 1D Variant array that contains the combined ranges. If you look at the spreadsheet after running `Main` Sub you should see the result reprinted in column F

[image]

Code:

```
Sub Main()

    Cells.Clear

    [A1] = 10: [A2] = 20: [A3] = 30: [B1] = 40: [B2] = 50: [B3] = 60: [C1] = 70: [C2] = 80: [C3] = 90

    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("A1:A3"): Set r2 = Range("B1:B3"): Set r3 = Range("C1:C3")

    Dim result As Variant
    result = VERTCATADO(r1, r2, r3)

    ' reprint back to spreadsheet in column F
    Range("F1").Resize(UBound(result, 1), UBound(result, 2)) = result

End Sub

Function VERTCATADO(ParamArray Ranges() As Variant)

    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1';"
    cn.Open

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.ActiveConnection = cn

    Dim query As String
    query = "SELECT * FROM "

    For Each v In Ranges
        If TypeOf v Is Excel.Range Then
            Dim r As Range
            Set r = v
            query = query & r.Address & " UNION ALL SELECT * FROM "
        End If
    Next

    If Len(query) > 25 Then
        query = Left(query, Len(query) - 25)
    End If

    query = Replace(query, "$", vbNullString)

    rs.Open query

    Dim rows As Variant
    rows = rs.GetRows

    rs.Close
    cn.Close

    VERTCATADO = Application.Transpose(rows)

End Function
```

*NOTE: this code doesn't really have any error handing so before using it in a production environment I'd recommend taking care of possible errors.*

Comment: Would like to give this a try, what references do I need to add to get the ADODB code working? I tried adding one called *Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security* but it doesn't seem to the the right one.

Comment: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library

Comment: That said, and I do still need to test this to make sure I've understood, if this function requires the ranges to all be passed in as columns then I don't think this is a feasible solution. We are using this on data for regressions and the columns in this case separate the observations and there can be many columns, too many to manually specify in a formula.

Comment: Thanks, I've added that reference. It now gives an error `The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'C:\Book1.XLSB'....`... on the `cn.Open` line. Maybe I need to save the workbook first... OK, saving the workbook as an XLSM file worked now with no errors, I'll tinker with the function to see if I can use it for out purposes.

Comment: OK this does work, I don't have to give it columns for ranges, I guess I misunderstood that part. What is the `If Len(query) > 25 Then` for? Are the queries really faster than loops? That's interesting to know.

Comment: Queries are A LOT faster than loops, specially in spreadsheets. If length of query is longer than 25 chacters then it subtracts the last part the loop has added `" UNION ALL SELECT * FROM "`. If you had an iterating variable you could use a different approach...

Comment: OK thanks, will keep this in mind. I was more hoping that there was a standard way of concatenating arrays in VBA.