# String Repeat function in VBA

Tags: strings, vba

VBA has built-in functions for repeating a single character:

> `Function String$(Number As Long, Character) As String`
>
> `Function Space$(Number As Long) As String`

But neither are of any use when you need to repeat a string that has more than one character.

You *could* repeat a string `"abcde"` 5 times by doing something crafty like:

`?Join(Split(String$(5,"."),"."),"abcde")`

But that is neither intuitive nor performant.

In Excel, there is also `WorksheetFunction.Rept`, but it is painfully slow, and only available in Excel.

So I made a custom function that builds the string, while minimizing the concatenations. In fact, it doesn't use *any* concatenation, but instead uses a buffer and `CopyMemory` to fill the buffer. And rather than filling the buffer one instance at a time, the code fills the buffer using a lookback that reduces the number of buffer writes exponentially:

Given a string `"abcde"` that repeats 5 times:

Create a buffer of 25 spaces

```
"                         "
```

1st buffer write - assign the string to the first buffer position

```
"abcde                    "
 [NEW]
```

2nd buffer write - copy the existing populated buffer (5 characters) into the next buffer position

```
"abcdeabcde               "
      [NEW]
```

3rd buffer write - copy the existing populated buffer (10 characters) into the next buffer position

```
"abcdeabcdeabcdeabcde     "
           [  NEW   ]`
```

4th buffer write - copy the lesser of the existing populated buffer (20 characters) and the remaining buffer (5 characters) into the next buffer position.

```
"abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde"
                     [NEW]
```

**StringRepeat**

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal Destination As Long, ByVal source As Long, ByVal Length As Long)

Public Function StringRepeat(number As Long, expression As String) As String

  Dim copyBufferLength As Long
  copyBufferLength = LenB(expression)

  'Create a buffer
  StringRepeat = Space$(number * Len(expression))

  Dim bufferLengthBytes As Long
  bufferLengthBytes = LenB(StringRepeat)

  Dim bufferPointer As Long
  bufferPointer = StrPtr(StringRepeat)

  'Copy the original expression to the start of the buffer
  CopyMemory bufferPointer, StrPtr(expression), copyBufferLength

  Do While copyBufferLength < bufferLengthBytes
    Dim remainingByteCount As Long
    'Check we're not going to overflow the buffer
    remainingByteCount = bufferLengthBytes - copyBufferLength
    If copyBufferLength > remainingByteCount Then
      CopyMemory bufferPointer + copyBufferLength, bufferPointer, remainingByteCount
    Else
      CopyMemory bufferPointer + copyBufferLength, bufferPointer, copyBufferLength
    End If
    copyBufferLength = copyBufferLength * 2
  Loop

End Function
```

The performance varies by the number of repeats, and the number of characters in the string to be repeated. I tried handling special cases like repeating a string 1 time (just return the string), and/or repeating a single character (return the result of `String$` instead), but while that speeds up the special cases, it slows down all other cases.

I'm not checking whether the `number` input is positive, and I'm not checking that the string to repeat is at least 1 character long, as for now, I'm focusing on performance.

In some instances (small values of `number`, short `expression` lengths), avoiding the Exponential lookback approach is not as fast as a straight-up loop and copy:

**RepeatString Simple**

```
Function StringRepeatSimple(number As Long, expression As String) As String

  Dim expressionLengthBytes As Long
  expressionLengthBytes = LenB(expression)

  'Create a buffer
  StringRepeatSimple= Space$(number * Len(expression))

  Dim bufferPointer As Long
  bufferPointer = StrPtr(StringRepeatSimple)

  Dim expressionPointer As Long
  expressionPointer = StrPtr(expression)

  Dim copyCounter As Long
  For copyCounter = 0 To number - 1
    CopyMemory bufferPointer + copyCounter * expressionLengthBytes, expressionPointer, expressionLengthBytes
  Next copyCounter 

End Function
```

Comment: I would just copy original string n times in a simple loop, no need to make first copy special or check for out of bounds error, just a simple loop with mem copy: first starting at 0, then at Len, 2*len, etc. Not sure about \0 byte in VB, so keep that in mind.

Comment: @elmigranto that's what the `StringRepeatSimple` alternative does, but for `number = 1000` and `expression = "ab"`, `StringRepeat` performs about 20 times faster than `StringRepeatSimple`.

Comment: In my testing, I had to check that CopyMemory wasn't going to copy past the end of the buffer, or Excel would crash.

Comment: Related: [a lightning-fast StringBuilder](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/67596/23788) - how does it compare?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I forgot about that question. Yes, *this* function *is* faster than the `StringBuilder`, but it's **_only_ 80 times faster** for 1000 repeats.

Comment: Thanks for this function. I have been trying to use it and am getting a type mismatch on StrPtr(StringRepeatSimple)   when putting ?StringRepeatSimple(5,"a") in immediate window. I wondered if this was due to 64 bit so tried changing Long to LongPtr in signature to no avail. Same error i.e. I did Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal Destination As LongPtr, ByVal source As LongPtr, ByVal Length As LongPtr) which is perhaps overkill.

Comment: I also tried Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr) ; same result.

Comment: @QHarr I don't have 64-bit office, but try checking the return type of `StrPtr`. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864270/strptr-type-mismatch-in-64-bit-mode

Comment: Thanks. I have seen that question which is why I tried fiddling with Long versus LongPtr. I will see if I can check the return type.

Comment: Apparently the return type is String using TypeName(StringRepeatSimple)

Comment: @QHarr I meant the return type of `StrPtr` (look in Object Browser with hidden members visible). You may need to change `bufferPointer` to be `As LongPtr` or as `LongLong`?

Comment: @QHarr This [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831(v=office.14).aspx) says *String converter. Returns a LongPtr on 64-bit versions, and a Long on 32-bit versions (4 bytes).*. If you can confirm it works, I'll update the post with compiler directives...

Comment: LongPtr is what I was expecting to see which is why I tried changing the signature. The object browser hidden member for StrPtr gives: Function StrPtr(Ptr As String) As LongPtr. I haven't yet managed to re-write so works but I am not that experienced.

Comment: @QHarr You're not reading my responses. In addition to changing the function declarations, you need to change `Dim bufferPointer As Long` to `Dim bufferPointer As LongPtr` and `Dim expressionPointer As Long` to `Dim expressionPointer As LongPtr`. That's why there are type mismatches.

Comment: I had changed bufferPointer. I didn't change expressionPointer though. Apologies.

Comment: With all as LongPtr including CopyMemory signature I get an empty string of length 5 instead of "aaaaa" i.e. ?len(StringRepeatSimple(5,"a") ) = 5

Comment: how about replace being more intuitive? :) `Debug.Print replace(space(10), " ", "abcde|")`

Comment: are you saying that/asking if using `REPLACE()` would be more intuitive?

Comment: This function is faster that StringRepeat()...
`Public Function Repeat$(ByVal n&, Pattern$) Dim r& r = Len(Pattern) If n < 1 Then Exit Function If r = 0 Then Exit Function If r = 1 Then Repeat = String$(n, Pattern): Exit Function Repeat = Space$(n * r) Mid$(Repeat, 1) = Pattern: If n > 1 Then Mid$(Repeat, r + 1) = Repeat End Function`

Answer (score 7):

FWIW, this might be a rare case where the `Mid` statement is apropos here. This doesn't require any API. This should yield similar performance characteristics since we only allocate the buffer once just as we do with the API version.

```
Public Function Replicate(RepeatString As String, NumOfTimes As Long)
    Dim s As String
    Dim c As Long
    Dim l As Long
    Dim i As Long

    l = Len(RepeatString)
    c = l * NumOfTimes
    s = Space$(c)

    For i = 1 To c Step l
        Mid(s, i, l) = RepeatString
    Next

    Replicate = s
End Function
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.

Comment: You are right about this being a case for Mid, but only if utilizing a special feature that is little known. Your version takes twice as long as OP's StringRepeat(). I don't have the Rep to add an answer here, so I will place my function in the next comment. Using Mid the way I have, my  function is FASTER that OP's StringRepeat()...

Comment: `Public Function Repeat$(ByVal n&, Pattern$)
    Dim r&
    r = Len(Pattern)
    If n < 1 Then Exit Function
    If r = 0 Then Exit Function
    If r = 1 Then Repeat = String$(n, Pattern): Exit Function
    Repeat = Space$(n * r)
    Mid$(Repeat, 1) = Pattern: If n > 1 Then Mid$(Repeat, r + 1) = Repeat
End Function`

Answer (score 1):

I see you want to use pointers and so maybe you should use pointer safe methods -

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal Destination As LongPtr, ByVal source As LongPtr, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
```

All the `Long` should also be `LongPtr`.

That being said `StrPtr` is undocumented and the user will get a *type mismatch* (at least on 64bit) unless `bufferPointer as LongPtr` is declared.

Same goes for `Dim expressionPointer As LongPtr`.

Otherwise, I think this is pretty clever, kudos.